# News Search APIs that Can be Used for Analytics

Tags: search-engine, api

The BOSS and Bing search APIs only allow customers to use them to create custom search applications. What I want to do is:

1. Use an API to find news articles
2. Perform some analytics on those articles
3. Display the results of those analytics on a website

Is there any news search API that allows this?

Comment: What analytics do you require it to be able to do? What would be an acceptable cost?

Comment: @NickWilde Not 100% sure one exactly what the analytics/acceptable cost would be. As an answer, I'd accept any API that satisfies the requirements I specified, even if I didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Google and bing now provide apis though ggl is very limited. I would then use data science happy languages like R or python. Some examples that may help clarify what and how; Tampa times has pinochio-meter. https://old.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/et90ci/oc_100_seconds_to_midnight_analyzing_3_years_of/ https://old.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/d0vrbl/mentions_of_recession_in_financial_news_websites/
https://old.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/esc23u/oc_word_cloud_from_titles_of_80k_news_articles_in/